# Error:refuced to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have created chrome extension which gets all page items and put all on first page.  To get other page items, i used iframe. But there is an error: refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'. How can i access on aliexpress website?. here is my code

```
  let ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", 'https://www.aliexpress.com/glosearch/api/product?CatId=' + catId + '&SearchText=' + searchText + '&catName=' + catName + 'SortType=default&page=' + nextPage + '&isrefine=y&');
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
        console.log(ifrm)
```

Comment: You can't when the site has explicitly set deny for that header. It is their right not to allow others to put their site in an iframe

Comment: You can. Simply remove the HTTP response header as shown in the linked topic.